# Case expression in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, case

I have been told to use case expression like this in one of the books I'm reading:

```
select name || case type_id
        when 7 then ' is a drink'
        when 8 then ' is a fruit'
        when 9 then ' is junkfood'
        when 13 then ' is seafood'
        else null
    end description
from foods
where description is not null
order by name
limit 10;
```

However, this gives me an error:

> Error while executing query: no such column: description

What I'm trying to do is avoiding the null values. So where is it going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query that you have written will not work in any dialect of SQL (sorry, but the example just doesn't work).  You can do what you want with a subquery:

```
select description
from (select name || (case type_id
                         when 7 then ' is a drink'
                         when 8 then ' is a fruit'
                         when 9 then ' is junkfood'
                         when 13 then ' is seafood'
                         else ''
                      end) as description,
              name
      from foods
    ) f
where description is not null
order by name
limit 10;
```

Note I changed the `else` clause to an empty substring rather than `NULL`.

Comment: The query I posted works from command prompt using sqlite3.exe, but not from SQLiteStudio (v2.1.5).

Comment: Even if it works in one version of SQLite, it is bad practice to depend on that functionality.  In general, you cannot refer to a column alias in the `where` clause at the same level where it is defined.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I'm happy to watch your back if you want to argue that SQLite isn't SQL. I find myself saying that several times a day.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' . . . Every database has its peculiarities and non-standard extensions.  Some are more unique than others (and supporting column aliases in the `where` clause would be *very* unique, insofar as you can use "vary" with "unique").

Comment: It appears SQLiteStudio (v2.1.5) is buggy one. It didn't even execute the query given in this answer but I already switched to `Database Browser for SQLite`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm willing to bet that the "foods" table doesn't have a "description" column, and that you're hoping the WHERE clause will pick up the column alias from your case statement.

It shouldn't do that. In standard SQL, the WHERE clause is evaluated before the SELECT clause. That means that any alias you provide in the SELECT clause is unavailable to the WHERE clause. But SQLite allows that. (See below. I haven't found this "feature" in the documentation.)

You *might* be looking for this.

```
where type_id is not null
```

Or you *might* be looking for this.

```
where type_id not in (7, 8, 9, 13)
```

---

Technically, a SQL engine just has to *behave* as if it evaluates the WHERE clause before the SELECT clause if it wants to comply with SQL standards. The effect on programmers like us is the same.

---

```
sqlite> create table foods (name varchar(15), type_id integer);
sqlite> insert into foods values ('Tequila', 7), ('Apple', 8),
   ...> ('Twinkie', 9), ('Tuna', 13), ('Olive oil', null);

sqlite> select name || case type_id
   ...>         when 7 then ' is a drink'
   ...>         when 8 then ' is a fruit'
   ...>         when 9 then ' is junkfood'
   ...>         when 13 then ' is seafood'
   ...>         else null
   ...>     end description
   ...> from foods
   ...> where description is not null
   ...> order by name
   ...> limit 10;

Apple is a fruit
Tequila is a drink
Tuna is seafood
Twinkie is junkfood
```

Comment: It was taken from the second edition of this [book](http://www.amazon.com/Definitive-Guide-SQLite-Mike-Owens/dp/1590596730).

Comment: It worked from command prompt using sqlite3.exe, but not from SQLiteStudio (v2.1.5).

Comment: Could be a difference in versions. I'm not sure how to help you track that down. The version the SQLite shows on startup from the command line is not necessarily the version of the SQLite library that SQLiteStudio links during compilation. SQLiteStudio doesn't seem to expose that information through its API.

Comment: It could be some bug or different versions. SQLiteStudio uses `SQLite3 engine version: 3.7.16.1` and it worked in `SQLite3 engine version: 3.8.4.3`